# Catalog price rules different after updating to 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, ce-1.9.2.0, ce-1.9.1.1

On 1.9.1.1, catalog price rule condition "Sku contains" works fine and the rule applies to bundle product types.

After updating to 1.9.2 "Sku contains" now means "Sku begins with" (value I enter must be in the beginning of the sku instead of anywhere in the sku) and the rule is not being applied to bundle product types unless I enter the EXACT sku.

Is anybody else having this issue? I confirmed it's an issue after updating because I switched back to 1.9.1.1 and the rules work fine now.

Comment: It is a bug and I had sames issue and reported to magento. Hopefully they fix in the new version. Also I am dealing with special price under product section too.